# How can I add wildcard support to a PostgreSQL query where one array must contain all the values from another array?

Tags: database, postgresql, search, tags, jsonb

Basically, I am trying to create a tag search system for images, in which each image has an array of tags within a jsonb field image_data, like so:

| id | image_data |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | `{tags: ['landscape', 'dog']}` |
| 2 | `{tags: ['landscape', 'cat']}` |
| 3 | `{tags: ['landscape', 'cats']}` |

The search consists of an array of tags and should return images that have all the searched tags. I did some experiments with the json operator <kbd>?&</kbd>. The problem is that this operation does not support wildcard characters.

```
select id from images where (image_data ->'tags') ?& array['landscape', 'cat%']
```

The above query should return the following results:

| id | image_data |
| --- | --- |
| 2 | `{tags: ['landscape', 'cat']}` |
| 3 | `{tags: ['landscape', 'cats']}` |

Is there any way to create a query similar to this, but with wildcard character support?

Answer (score 2):

You can do this by expanding a JSON array to a set of text values with `jsonb_array_elements_text`. then check that each image has at least the total number of searching tags (in this case we have 2):

```
select id, image_data
from (
  select id, image_data, value as tag
  from images i, jsonb_array_elements_text(i.image_data -> 'tags')
) as s
where tag = 'landscape' or tag like 'cat%'
group by id, image_data
having count(1) >= array_length(array['landscape', 'cat%'], 1)
```

Result :

```
id  image_data
3   {"tags": ["landscape", "cats"]}
2   {"tags": ["landscape", "cat"]}
```

[Demo here](https://dbfiddle.uk/RpUTMRxR)

Answer (score 1):

You're right in that the ?& operator doesn't support wildcards, but there's a way around that by using the unnest function, which will extract the elements of the array into a set of rows.

I think yu're right that `?&` doesn't support wildcards -- you can go around it by using unnest functions that extract the elts from the array into a set of rows.

- unnest tags array
- check each tag individually using `LIKE`
- group by id and image_data (include groups where # of matched tags = # of search tags)
- array_length(array['cat%'], 1) could be replaced with # of search tags

```
SELECT id, image_data
FROM (
    SELECT id, image_data, tag
    FROM images, unnest((image_data -> 'tags')::text[]) as tag
) s
WHERE tag LIKE 'cat%'
GROUP BY id, image_data
HAVING count(*) = array_length(array['cat%'], 1);
```

- returns images that have one or more tags that start with `cat`